# C# Downloading - Interesting error

Tags: c#, download

I'm currently doing a patcher program in C#, but there's an interesting error. 
In the code, there's a loop for all of the links an file names, and the program needs to download them. Code: (fájlNév = fileName, letöltött = downloaded, összes = all, JelenlegiLetöltés = CurrentDownload, állás = state)

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        string[] remoteUrl = new string[4] { "https://www.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/spni307vmk4zng9/", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsa29pelfwgk5ha/", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcn0wy2te4zqj1i/" };

        string[] fájlNév = new string[4] { "alut.dll", "DevIL.dll", "fltkdll.dll", "glew32.dll" };
        string fájlNévAlap = "BlackBox.dll", WebResource = null;

        int letöltött = 0;
        int össz = remoteUrl.Length;

        for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < remoteUrl.Length && x < fájlNév.Length; i++, x++)
        {
            WebResource = remoteUrl[i] + fájlNév[x];
            letöltött++;
            // MessageBox.Show(letöltött.ToString());
            jelenlegiLetöltés.Text = fájlNév[x]; 
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(WebResource,fájlNév[x]);
            double állás = letöltött / össz * 100;
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(állás);
        }
```

So, the problem is, the program only downloads the first file (for 4 times), and the other 3 files are just the renamed versions of the first file. 
Can someone say what is the problem?

Thanks, 
Tomco

Here's an image showing the error: [image: http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/9339/erroraz.png] (as you can see, all of the files sizes are equal to the first file's size)

Comment: Get rid of either i or x. There's no situation, in the code you have there, where their values won't be equal. So don't confuse things by having both.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried copypasta'ing this code into LINQPad and running it (with some minor alterations, mainly renaming variables so I could read them easily), and noticed that the "file" that's getting downloaded is an HTML dump...is that what you are seeing as well?

From first glances, it would appear that the simple URI you are using is insufficient to use as a download link - the link in that HTML blob has extra query string parameters like hash, etc.

An example link from the HTML:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/alut.dll?token_hash=AAHQmybYdR44TRrS9bWQWV7jlZBzZQ-mmmjNy1Kv_qR4cg&amp;dl=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I can't use the array technique with this type of link. Maybe I need to put all of the links in different strings?

Comment: @Tomc0 It seems a bit more complicated than that - the simple "drop box url + filename" format is not enough information to point to the actual file; I would guess there is some aspect of a "session" that dropbox requires to allow access (hence the token hash in that url I posted)

Comment: But then why can it download the first file?

Comment: @Tomc0 Have you examined the file it's downloading? I'll bet that it's actually that HTML file.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. That's a HTML document. Thanks. (or maybe php, I don't know) Then I need to change my code. But I don't know how, because I don't want 20 strings :S

Comment: Well, first thing I'd do is look here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers - very likely you can use DropBox's REST API to grab what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try the API.

Comment: Just another question. How I can do a link like this from a simple https://www.dropbox.com/s/62tt9w194xefk7t/alut.dll?

Comment: @Tomc0 Unfortunately, I have no experience with the dropbox api - although I imagine the docs at that url would help.

Comment: I didn't mean the API, just how did you do that link?

Comment: Nothing special, just pasted it in?